# How to implement a message with a custom function code in pymodbus?

Tags: pymodbus, pymodbus3

I'm currently trying to implement a modbus request that has a custom function code. The implementation is based on this example: [custom_message.py](https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/blob/master/examples/common/custom_message.py)

```
import struct
from pymodbus.pdu import ModbusRequest, ModbusResponse
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.0.55')
connection = client.connect()

class CustomModbusResponse(ModbusResponse):
    # some fancy decoding should be done here..
    pass

class CustomModbusRequest(ModbusRequest):
    function_code = 55

    def __init__(self, address):
        ModbusRequest.__init__(self)
        self.address = address
        self.count = 1

    def encode(self):
        return struct.pack('>HH', self.address, self.count)

    def decode(self, data):
        self.address, self.count = struct.unpack('>HH', data)

    def execute(self, context):
        if not (1 <= self.count <= 0x7d0):
            return self.doException(ModbusExceptions.IllegalValue)
        if not context.validate(self.function_code, self.address, self.count):
            return self.doException(ModbusExceptions.IllegalAddress)
        values = context.getValues(self.function_code, self.address,
                                   self.count)
        return CustomModbusResponse(values)

request = CustomModbusRequest(0)
result = client.execute(request)
print(result)
```

The request works as expected. I can see the correct response on the network layer. However I can't parse the result. Pymodbus is throwing the following error:

```
DEBUG:pymodbus.factory:Factory Response[55]
ERROR:pymodbus.factory:Unable to decode response Modbus Error: Unknown response 55
ERROR:pymodbus.transaction:Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Unable to decode request
```

The example states that in this case, I would have to:

> If you implement a new  method that is not currently implemented, you
>   must register the request and response with a ClientDecoder factory.

Is there an elegant way to do this without patching the library?

Comment: You will have to manually add your `response` to `ClientDecoder. __function_table` . There is no factory method defined to add the custom message. You can raise a feature request or submit a patch if you have one handy.